# Kerberos with Active Directory

Tags: proxy, active-directory, kerberos

So I've setup kerberos on Ubuntu in various ways (likewise-open, winbind, etc) and keep coming up with the same problem. kinit works fine and I get the initial ticket, but when I try to access a proxy authenticated with IWA, it always makes a request for the new ticket as HTTP/proxy.local, which fails. I'm assuming that it should be HTTP/proxy.EXAMPLE.COM but can't figure out what's going wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution. Added my proxy to `/etc/hosts` to force to resolve to proper address for Kerberos.